# Table header doesn't stick to the top

Tags: html, css

Table header doesn't stick to the top (see code below). It seems to be in conflict with `#app { overflow: auto }` because when I remove it, the header sticks as expected.

Unfortunately I can't remove that code as I need it to make the layout work (table needs to overflow both horizontally and vertically).

I would appreciate if anyone could share a workaround.

Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#app {
  overflow: auto;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


table { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;

  text-align: left;
  padding: .3rem;
  width: 25rem;
}

#table-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
    <header id="header">
      <p>Site Title</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </header>

    <div id="app">
      <table>
        <tr id='table-header'>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: The better way to put your table into the #app., so that only the table would move horizontally or vertically as its size increases. Otherwise, the whole body would do that and it would be a bad UX

Comment: @AbinThaha Agreed, and I've made an edit, but it doesn't change the table header behavior

Comment: If it working now as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/create-a-sticky-sidebar#:%7E:text=Troubleshooting%20position%20sticky,-Sometimes%2C%20position%20sticky&text=Position%20sticky%20will%20most%20probably,do%20not%20support%20sticky%20positioning.) reference

> Position sticky will most probably not work if overflow is set to
> hidden, scroll, or auto on any of the parents of the element

The solution mentioned [here](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526) is to set height along with the overflow to get this fixed. If thats possible, you can try the one below.

I have added the below one to get this fixed.

```
#app {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#app {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

th,
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;

  text-align: left;
  padding: .3rem;
  width: 25rem;
}

#table-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <header id="header">
    <p>Site Title</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </header>

  <table>
    <tr id='table-header'>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice research :)

Answer (score 0):

**Position sticky will most probably not work if overflow is set to hidden, scroll, or auto on any of the parents of the element.**

So, in your case `#app` is the parent of the `table-header` which has the `overflow` property... which is why the sticky is messing up...A simple workaround would be changing the divs (which I did in this solution), it may change your requirement but that would be the only effective quick workaround.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#app {
  overflow: auto;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


table { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;

  text-align: left;
  padding: .3rem;
  width: 25rem;
}

#table-header {
  position: sticky; 
  top: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
    <header id="header">
      <p>Site Title</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </header>

   
      <table>
        <tr id='table-header'>
         <div id="app">
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum…</td>
```